# Regd : getting value from json url

Tags: android

I want to get the id ^& content value in http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting

What i tried is,

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(parsingUrl);

        // If you have array
        JSONArray resultArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("id"); // Here you will get the Array

        // Iterate the loop
        for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length(); i++) {
            // get value with the NODE key
            JSONObject obj = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String name =  obj.getString("content");
        }

        // If you have object
        //String result1 = jsonObj.getString("result");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The url that your mentioned dont have json arrays, parsing will be like

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(resultfromUrl);

        int id = jsonObj.getInt("id"); 
        String name =  jsonObj.getString("content");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: can u test above code u mentioned.I tried oncreate.It not setting value

Comment: Now i am not makine request.I am adding following code in oncreate.Is it not possible without AsynchTask

Comment: new JSONObject(*resultfromUrl*)... Your have to make a AsyncTask to fetch the result from url. Passing url directly in JSONObject wont work.

Comment: Impossible without AsyncTask

Comment: plz send me java file.here